# Replace characters in List of strings

Tags: swift, swift3

I've sorted my `list` with objects by propertie `time` which is `String` not `date`.

The sample output before sorting  :

```
07:05:10 AM
07:05:01 AM
07:04:49 AM
07:04:44 AM 
06:53:58 AM
06:53:47 AM
01:03:21 AM
12:03:21 AM
```

and after invoking instrudtion :

```
self.myList = self.myList.sorted { $0.mytime < $1.mytime }
```

going to looks like this :

```
01:03:21 AM
06:53:47 AM
06:53:58 AM
07:04:44 AM 
07:04:49 AM
07:05:01 AM
07:05:10 AM
12:03:21 AM
```

Could I replace `12:03:21 AM` to `00:03:21 AM` only when it is `AM` and `12` at the beginning ?

Or there is different way to do this ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is an XY-problem. You should not compare dates based on a *string* representation. Convert them to `Date` (or some numerical timestamp) instead.

Comment: 12:03 AM and 00:03 AM is not the same time

Comment: You are not sorting it correctly. It should sort first based on the  am/pm then you can sort based on the prefix (time). I would sort the dates first and get the String later

Comment: @CasperZandbergen: What OP *probably* means is that 12:03 AM is earlier than 01:00 AM, so (s)he wants to tweak the string in order to get the comparison right.

Comment: Converting all strings to a (**24 hour**) HH:MM:SS format for comparison would be another option.

Comment: @MartinR could u show me an example using `.map` ? Or there is no option to do this with `.map` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. Always compare dates in this manner!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var arrayOfDates = ["07:05:10 AM",
                        "07:05:01 AM",
                        "07:04:49 AM",
                        "07:04:44 AM",
                        "06:53:58 AM",
                        "06:53:47 AM",
                        "01:03:21 AM",
                        "12:03:21 AM"]

    // This will throw an error if any of your dates are 
    // misformatted, so handle that appropriately.                  
    arrayOfDates.sort() { $0.toDate()!.compare($1.toDate()!) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending }
    print("Descending: \(arrayOfDates)")

    arrayOfDates.sort() { $0.toDate()!.compare($1.toDate()!) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }
    print("Ascending: \(arrayOfDates)")
}

extension String {
    func toDate() -> Date? {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
    if let date = formatter.date(from: self) {
        return date
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

//If you need a string version of the date you can use this as well
extension Date {
    func toString() -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to compile that?

Comment: Thanks! That's exactlly what i wanted. I was looking for this. Mean while I've made a solution with looping but it looks dirty. I will stay with your implementation :)

Comment: @MartinR No I didn't.... I wrote it from memory. Is there a problem with it? It uses code that I use on a daily basis, so if there is a bug it is small.

Comment: @Sethmr: It does not compile. Try it yourself.

Comment: Derpy seems to have been able to figure that out, but feel free to figure out what I mistyped and correct it.... ohhhhh I missed func LOL

Comment: Please *test* your code, so that is has value for future readers as well.  I am not talking about a missing "func". `arrayOfDates` needs to be a  *variable*. The return value of `toDate()` needs to be unwrapped.

Comment: Btw, `Date` values can be compared with `<`.

Comment: Is that new to Swift 3? Even if it isn't, I think that seeing the words Ascending and Descending help visualize the sorting of dates and make the code more readable. Dates aren't smaller or larger... they are past or future (which I think correlate better).

Comment: Also If you would like to use those method on the exact property of the object then it would look like :             `self.myList.sort() { $0.mytime.toDate()?.compare($1.mytime.toDate()!) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }`