# Realm subquery sorted by Date

Tags: swift, realm

I have the following model:

```
class User: Object {
   dynamic var name = ""
   let events = List<Event>() 
}

class Event : Object {
   dynamic var description = ""
   let dates = List<Date>() 
}

class Date : Object {
    dynamic var date = "" //string 
}
```

Is there any good way to query/filter for the (one) event with closes date to current date? If not possible, how should the modell be modified, i saw that subqueries are only available with @count i.e. realm.objects(Company.self).filter("employees.@count > 5")

Comment: I literally was just answering a similar question. Checkout [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999852/replace-characters-in-list-of-strings/43000512#43000512)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a shame that `date` isn't an `NSDate` property since you could easily just sort by descending order, and then use `LinkingObjects` to look up the `Event` in which that `Date` object belongs:

```
class Event : Object {
   dynamic var description = ""
   let dates = List<Date>() 
}

class Date : Object {
    dynamic var date = NSDate()
    let events = LinkingObjects(fromType: Event.self, property: "dates")
}

let realm = try! Realm()
let latestDate = realm.objects(Date.self).sorted("date", ascending: false).first
let latestEvent = latestDate.events.first
```

Unfortunately, as `date` is a string, that might not work. You could try and used `sorted()` on `date`, but it will be sorting alphabetically, and not chronologically, so you may not get the latest date.

If that's the case, you'll need to manually implement a loop through each `Date` object, parse it and perform the sorting yourself.

Comment: thank you @TiM i think i can change that to an NSDate and not having a string there.